# Only allow saving to PDF in Excel 2007/2010

Tags: excel, pdf, printing

Is there any way to force excel to always print a file in PDF format?  For some reason the standard code I found (on this site and others) doesn't seem to work.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
cFileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

I've got a simple Input box to capture the file name, and I'd like to prevent them from doing anything else.  Ideally, I'd like to put this code into my BeforeSave event and my BeforePrint event so that the only thing they can do is print to PDF.  Is this possible?

Comment: What does your code do instead of working?

Comment: Make sure that your inputbox should capture the entire path of the file with its name, for example C:\Users\SONY\Desktop\Book1.pdf

Comment: if I don't enter a complete path, wouldn't it default to the current path?  I was planning to override the path to a default once I got this to work, so I only care about the name.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting an error like this or running the code?

"Automation error: The object invoked has disconnected from its clients" error message in Excel 2000

If yes then have a look at the link below

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813120

Use the code below in worksheet

```
    Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Macro1
    End Sub
```

Add the following code in a new module

```
    Sub Macro1()
    cfilename = "C:\Users\SONY\Desktop\Book1.pdf" 'you can use the input box method to get the desired file name and location
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
            cfilename, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
            False
    End Sub
```

Comment: no I'm not getting any error - it just doesn't save.  No errors, nothing.

Comment: No errors, but no PDF file is generated either.  It just seems to run but no output.

Comment: Hi Jay, I have used the same code given by you and it is working fine on saving the sheet. I get an error on clicking print.

Comment: Kannan - are you saying that it saves to PDF just fine but it won't print to PDF?  OK I'm totally confused.

Comment: @jay did you put the first part of the code from KannanS into the 'ThisWorkbook' code pane - it must go there to trap the BeforeSave Event. The Printing Event rerouting will require a separate piece of code

Comment: @brettdj: yes you are right. You have to use a code like `Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)` When I used the code, I get an error "Automation error: The object invoked has disconnected from its clients" error message in Excel 2000.

Answer (score 0):

A long time ago I used the opensource PDFPrinter in combination with Excel.  Here is some of the code I wrote that seems to do what you want. Maybe you can use this as a start for your own solution?

'Print the saved file as a pdf in the same directory

```
KTCurrentFilePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path 'Store current FilePath

'Define Variables for PDF printjob

Dim pdfjob As Object

Dim KTPDFName As String

Dim KTPDFPath As String

Dim KTPCurrentPrinter As String
```

'Set Variable Values

```
KTPDFName = Range("MyPDFName").Value & ".pdf"

KTPDFPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator

KTPCurrentPrinter = Application.ActivePrinter
```

'Check if worksheet is empty and exit if so

```
If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.UsedRange) Then Exit Sub
```

'Start PDF Engine

```
Set pdfjob = CreateObject("PDFCreator.clsPDFCreator")

On Error GoTo 0

With pdfjob

    If .cStart("/NoProcessingAtStartup") = False Then

        MsgBox "Can't initialize PDFCreator.", vbCritical + _

            vbOKOnly, "PrtPDFCreator"

            Application.ActivePrinter = KTPCurrentPrinter

        Exit Sub

    End If

    .cOption("UseAutosave") = 1

    .cOption("UseAutosaveDirectory") = 1

    .cOption("AutosaveDirectory") = KTPDFPath

    .cOption("AutosaveFilename") = KTPDFName

    .cOption("AutosaveFormat") = 0    ' 0 = PDF

    .cClearCache

End With
```

'Print the document to PDF

```
ActiveSheet.PrintOut copies:=1, ActivePrinter:="PDFCreator"
```

'Wait until the print job has entered the print queue

```
Do Until pdfjob.cCountOfPrintjobs = 1

    DoEvents

Loop

pdfjob.cPrinterStop = False
```

'Wait until PDF creator is finished then release the objects

```
Do Until pdfjob.cCountOfPrintjobs = 0

    DoEvents

Loop

pdfjob.cClose

Set pdfjob = Nothing
```

'Reset Printer to default

```
Application.ActivePrinter = KTPCurrentPrinter
```

End Sub

Regards,

Robert Ilbrink

Comment: Robert - is it required that I have a PDF creator add-in to get my PDF routine to work?  I thought Excel came with one built in?